# how to add column and make one column in sas

Tags: sql, join, sas

I want to add 3 columns and make one column below is my code.if value present in both column say b and c i want any value in d column

```
data a;
    infile datalines missover;
    input id industry $;
datalines;
1  a
2  b
3
;
run;

data b;
    infile datalines missover;
    input id industry $;
datalines;
1  
2  
3  c
;
run;

data c;
    infile datalines missover;
    input id industry $;
datalines;
1  
2  
3  d
;
run;
```

output should be

```
id industry
1  a
2  b
3  c or d (any)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    select id, min(industry)
    from ((select id, industry from a
          ) union all
          (select id, industry from b
          ) union all
          (select id, industry from c
          ) 
         ) abc
    group by id;
run;
```

Note that this will return any id in any of the tables.  This is a handy approach if the tables do not have the same set of ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `coalesce`:

```
proc sql;
    create table temp as select
        a.id, coalesce(a.industry, b.industry, c.industry) as industry
        from a
        left join b
        on a.id = b.id
        left join c
        on a.id = c.id;
quit;
```